# Angular 1.5 Nested Component Bind parent Value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components

I am new to angularjs. I am trying angular 1.5 nested component. Can I bind parent component property in child component.

Ex:

```
<div ng-app='cbsApp' ng-controller='cbsCnt as ct'>
    <cbs-cus-comp com-bind='ct.name'>
        <child child-com-bind='cbsCusCompCntAs.name'></child>
    </cbs-cus-comp>
</div>
```

I can get ct.name value in com-bind. But can't get cbsCusCompCntAs.name in child-com-bind. (cbsCusCompCntAs is cbs-cus-comp controller)

Working Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/axQwTn?p=preview

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your first case you are referring directly to the controller scope via `controllerAs`.

When using components in angular 1.5 you can get hold of your parent component via `require` which will make parent's properties available after `$onInit` as per [Components Documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.3/docs/guide/component):

> Note that the required controllers will not be available during the
>   instantiation of the controller, but they are guaranteed to be
>   available just before the $onInit method is executed!

In your specific case you can update the *child* component to require the parent:

```
var child = {
    require     :  {parentComp:'^cbsCusComp'},
    template    :  'Child : <b{{cbsCusChildCompCntAs.childComBind}}</b>',
    controller  :  cbsCusChildCompCnt,
    controllerAs:  'cbsCusChildCompCntAs'
    };
```

and its controller to get the data you need (*I used the same names as you just to see it work*):

```
function cbsCusChildCompCnt(){
  this.$onInit = function() {
    this.childComBind = this.parentComp.name;
  };
}
```

Updated plunker is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/C7VASc?p=preview).

Answer (score 4):

Wow... what a wonderful example...
Took me a while to analyse it... so, I wrote my own (I think a bit more readable) version.
I really do not know how to work with Plunker... so here's the code...
**Extract from my index.html file**

```
<div ng-controller='appCtrl as ctrl'>
    <parent bind-id='ctrl.name'>
        <child bind-toid='parentCtrlAs.name'></child>
    </parent>
</div>
```

**The .js file**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var 
    parentComponent =   
    {
        bindings    :   
        {
            bindId:'='
        },
        controller  : parentCtrl,
        controllerAs: 'parentCtrlAs',
        restrict    : 'A',
        transclude  : true,
        templateUrl : 'parent.html',
    };

var 
    childComponent =    
    {
        controller  : childCtrl,
        controllerAs: 'childCtrlAs',
        restrict    : 'A',
        require     :
        {
            myParent    :'^parent'
        },
        templateUrl :   'child.html',
};


angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('appCtrl'   , appCtrl)
    .component('parent'     , parentComponent)
    .component('child'      , childComponent);


function appCtrl(){
    this.name = 'Main..';
}

function childCtrl(){
    this.$onInit = function() {
        this.bindToid = this.myParent.name;
    };
}

function parentCtrl(){
    this.name   =   'Parent Component';
}
```

})();

Hope it helps,
Regards,
Johnny

Answer (score 4):

Although using the "require" parameter works, it creates a tightly bound relationship between the component acting as a child, which uses the "require" parameter, and the component acting as a parent, which consumes the child functionality.

A better solution is to use component communication as shown [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component/).

Basically, you define a binding function in the child component definition, like so,

```
angular.module('app').component('componentName', {
templateUrl: 'my-template.html',
bindings: {
       myFunction: '&'
},
controller: function() { // Do something here}
});
```

Then, in the parent markup you provide a function to call,

Parent HTML

```html
<user-list select-user="$ctrl.selectUser(user)">
</user-list>
```

Finally, in the parent controller, provide an implementation of the selectUser function.

Here's a working [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/0YAaq5K6NzSvWSyNGAmU?p=preview).